# Shell script : Displaying network interface and their corresponding ip address in a table format

Tags: bash, sh

I want to display network interface and their ip address in a table format using shell script. I have this code

```
#! /bin/bash
interface=$(ifconfig | cut -d ' ' -f1| tr '\n' ' ' | tee save.tmp)
ip=$(ifconfig | awk -F':' '/inet addr/&&!/127.0.0.1/{split($2,_," ");print _[1]}')
echo $interface
echo $ip
```

The output of this code is

```
eth0 vmnet1 vmnet8
10.30.10.226 192.168.142.1 192.168.3.1
```

I want like this

```
eth0  10.30.10.226 
vmnet1 192.168.142.1
vmnet8 192.168.3.1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you post the output of the `ifconfig` and `ip` commands, it will probably be possible to skip a few steps of processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange it like this:

```
for iface in $(ifconfig | cut -d ' ' -f1| tr '\n' ' ')
do 
  addr=$(ip -o -4 addr list $iface | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)
  printf "$iface\t$addr\n"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my shell script** *(hope it helps)* :

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

echo -e "+-----------+-----------------+\n| Interface | IP Address      |\n+-----------+-----------------+"
for iface in $(ip -o -4 addr list | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')
do
    ipaddr=$(ip -o -4 addr list $iface | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)
    printf "|%10s | %-16s|\n" $iface $ipaddr
done
echo "+-----------+-----------------+"
```

**Output:**

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| Interface | IP Address      |
+-----------+-----------------+
|        lo | 127.0.0.1       |
| enp0s31f6 | 10.10.10.100    |
|   wlp61s0 | 10.11.11.111    |
|      tun0 | 10.20.20.200    |
+-----------+-----------------+
```